# Как сделать два дива в столбик с резиновой высотой?

Tags: html, css

Есть два дива в столбик, у первого дива высота динамическая (то есть неизвестная) в зависимости от контента. Второй див должен занимать всю оставшуюся высоту минус высота первого дива. Есть ли возможность реализовать подобное без javascript и без table?

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
     <div class="title">text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
     <div class="body">text</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
   height: 90%; width: 200px;
   background: red;
   padding: 0 5px;
   position: fixed;
}
.title {
   background: blue;
}
.body {
   background: yellow;
   height: 100%;
}
```

JSFIDDLE

https://jsfiddle.net/jetvsg8n/

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам поможет flex с ориентацией по колонкам и пропорциями 0 и 1.

```css
.wrapper {
    height: 150px; width: 150px;
    background: red;
    padding: 0 5px;
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.title {
    background: blue;
    flex: 0;
}
.body {
    background: yellow;
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="title">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <div class="body">text text text text text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но результат какой-то странный. В вашем ответе второй (желтый блок) занял вообще всю высоту, не вычитая высоту первого дива.

Comment: @user2164613 Что значит "всю высоту"? Ну вот смотрите, обновил ответ, теперь wrapper квадратный, пропорции хорошо видно. Если это не то, то я ваш вопрос не понял.

Comment: Блок body занял всю высоту родителя wrapper, а блока title (синего) вообще не видно на вашем примере. Не знаю как еще понятнее суть изложить: Высота блока body должна быть 100% минус высота блока title.

Comment: @user2164613 Какой у вас брузер? IE6? Должно выглядеть так: http://i.imgur.com/vqZntQA.png

Comment: У меня (Версия 47.0.2526.106 m (64-bit) Вы используете самую новую версию Chrome.) на windows 10. И выглядит у меня это так: http://i.imgur.com/lZsuw7R.png

Comment: Safari 9.0, Mac OS X 10.11, так же не работает – http://joxi.ru/D2PBxOBH1M1Jr3

Comment: лишний `flex: 0;` у класcа title. Вообще лучше в данном случае пользоваться не алиасом flex, а конкретными свойствами: flex-grow, flex-shrink

Comment: @Grundy лишним он оказался только у меня например. Ведь у автора все нормально. С такой странной поддержкой встает вопрос целесообразности использовать flex, но других способов я так понимаю нет.

Comment: @user2164613, всегда есть несколько способов решить задачу, просто некоторые например могут показаться некрасивыми, например использовать таблицу с двумя ячейками

Comment: @Grundy я понимаю, но в моем случае условие задачи таково: без таблиц, без скриптов. :) В принципе flex это решение, однако открыт вопрос с поддержкой.

Comment: @user2164613, вот хороший [guide по flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) просто надо по лучше разобраться со свойствами, ну  поддержка заявлена у [всех основных версий](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox). Кстати в edge - работает так как у автора :-)

Answer (score 0):

Такой результат ожидается?

```css
html, body  {
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper{
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  background: #68AAAB;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
.div--top {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
  background: #022827
}
.div--bottom {
  -webkit-box-flex: 2;
  -webkit-flex: 2;
      -ms-flex: 2;
          flex: 2;
  background: #B5B74A
}
```

```html
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="div--top"></div>
    <div class="div--bottom"></div>
</div>
```